# Nuxt Content - Display Content after loading from firebase

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, markdown, nuxt-content

How can we use `@nuxt/content` to display a markdown from a string? The idea is, I want to fetch some data from my firestore database, then display it.

So it'll be like,

```
const data = "
# Title
So this data has been returned from firebase, we just need to future out how to render it using a markdown previewer.
"
```

Now in the template, I want to just use `nuxt-content` to display this string (`data`)

Please note, I'd preferably like to use this `@nuxt/content` only for this, I'm aware of other markdown previerers, but I have some static files too which are being rendered using this same library, so I just want to reuse it to render stuff from database too.

Comment: Hi @bacon-delight, do you have a code example for us? Displaying content should work with <nuxt-content :document="data" />.

Comment: Hi @hawc, I tried something like: `<nuxt-content :document="data"></nuxt-content>` and the `data` is the string posted in the question. It didn't render anything.

Comment: It could help to simply rename the variable. The keyword "data" is already defined by Vue. So you're probably not accessing you const called "data", but the Vue property called "data".

Comment: Yes yes, I have been using a different variable name in the project, just for posting the question here, I for some reason put it like that. Sorry for the confusion, but it's not working with any other name as well.